# Hot to make a query which can have date or be empty

Tags: sql

Query bellow WHEN I set OR is giving me all values from table, when I set AND a.kraj IS NULL doesnt give me any.

How can I make query to display all records from table where a.kraj < CURRENT_DATE() but a.kraj can be empty as it is not required to be set. a.kraj can have date but can be empty as well

```
SELECT a.id, b.naziv, a.pocetak, a.kraj, a.status 
FROM radni_nalozi a 
LEFT JOIN artikli b ON a.idArtikal = b.ArtId 
WHERE a.status = 1 AND CURRENT_DATE() >= a.pocetak AND a.kraj < CURRENT_DATE() OR a.kraj IS NULL;
```

I had no luck, I am getting in circle with this no idea what has to be changed.

Comment: Your WHERE clause needs parentheses. AND goes before OR.

Answer (score 1):

You want the condition `a.kraj < CURRENT_DATE()` or `a.kraj` itself is `NULL`.  Use appropriate parentheses:

```
SELECT a.id, b.naziv, a.pocetak, a.kraj, a.status 
FROM radni_nalozi a 
LEFT JOIN artikli b ON a.idArtikal = b.ArtId 
WHERE a.status = 1 AND
      CURRENT_DATE() >= a.pocetak AND (a.kraj < CURRENT_DATE() OR a.kraj IS NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply indicate the logical intent with parenthesis:

```
WHERE (a.status = 1 AND CURRENT_DATE() >= a.pocetak AND a.kraj < CURRENT_DATE())
      OR a.kraj IS NULL;
```